# How to insert a command before ending of all `tikzpicture` while using `external` tikz-library?

Tags: tikz-external

When I was using `tikz` package with `external` library, before ending of every `tikzpicture` environment, I want to insert a command such as `\node at (current bounding box.south)[below=3mm]{\small\textbf{note}};` but this command was not be displayed by pdflatex.

When I cleared `\tikzexternalize` command, it normally exported. Please fix my below document (hold back `\tikzexternalize`). Thank for your help!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,external}
\tikzexternalize

\let\oldtikzpicture\tikzpicture
\let\endoldtikzpicture\endtikzpicture

\renewenvironment{tikzpicture}[1][]{\oldtikzpicture[#1]}{
    \node at (current bounding box.south)[below=3mm]{\small\textbf{note}};
    \endoldtikzpicture}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,>=triangle 45,x=1.0cm,y=1.0cm]
\draw [line width=0.8pt] (0.,0.) circle (2.5cm);
\draw [line width=0.8pt] (0.,0.) --(0,-4);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,external}% arrows is deprecated
\tikzexternalize
\tikzset{%
  every picture/.style={%
    execute at end picture={%
      \node at (current bounding box.south)[below=3mm]{\small\textbf{note}};
    },
  },
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,>=triangle 45,x=1.0cm,y=1.0cm]
  \draw [line width=0.8pt] (0.,0.) circle (2.5cm);
  \draw [line width=0.8pt] (0.,0.) --(0,-4);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: noted]

Comment: Sorry but I have one more question. We have ##1 parameter when declare sub-environment or sub-command. Does any have ##1 parameter when declare subsub-environment or command?

Comment: @Kanegusa199 I didn't use `##1` as far as I can tell, so I'm not sure what you're referring to. You'd use `##1` if defining a macro inside the definition of another one. Otherwise, `#1` refers to an argument of the outer macro.

Comment: You wouldn't need to double the hashes in your example, I don't think, because you want to refer to an argument passed to the outer macro.